# frame does not get raised when using frame.tkraise()

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to raise my 'Search' frame above 'Login' frame when user clicks on the 'Login' button. I think this might have something to do with how I'm stacking my frames, but am not sure what it exactly is.

I tested if the show_frame function runs after user clicks on the 'Login' button, and it does, but the frame does not get lifted.

```
import tkinter as tk

class App(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)

        root = tk.Frame(self)

        self.screen_w = root.winfo_screenwidth()
        self.screen_h = root.winfo_screenheight()

        self.frames = {}
        for F in (Login, Search):
            page_name = F.__name__
            frame = F(parent=root, controller=self)
            self.frames[page_name] = frame

            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame("Search")

    def show_frame(self, page_name):
        '''Show a frame for the given page name'''
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        frame.tkraise()

class Login(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):

        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller

        self.screen_w = controller.screen_w
        self.screen_h = controller.screen_h

        self.display()

    def display(self):

        #login page (frame)
        self.login_page = tk.Frame(width=self.screen_w, height=self.screen_h, background="#ABEBC6")
        self.login_section = tk.Frame(width=100, height=100, background="#52BE80")

        self.login_page.pack()
        self.login_section.place(in_=self.login_page, anchor="c", relx = 0.5, rely = 0.5, relheight = 0.5, relwidth = 0.5)

        self.login_button = tk.Button(self.login_section, text='Login', fg = 'black', bg = 'green')
        self.login_button.place(relx = 0.5, rely = 0.55, relheight = 0.1, relwidth = 0.4, anchor = 'c')
        self.login_button.bind('<Button-1>', self.check_login)

    def check_login(self, event):

        self.controller.show_frame('Search')

class Search(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):

        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller

        self.screen_w = controller.screen_w
        self.screen_h = controller.screen_h

        self.display()

    def display(self):

            #search page (frame)
            self.search_page = tk.Frame(width=self.screen_w, height=self.screen_h, background="#85C1E9")
            self.search_section = tk.Frame(width=100, height=100, background="#5DADE2")

            self.search_page.pack()
            self.search_section.place(in_=self.search_page, relx = 0.5, rely = 0.5, relheight = 0.5, relwidth = 0.5, anchor = 'center')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root of your problem is that you are putting inner frames in the root window rather than in the page.

You need to change this:

```
self.login_page = tk.Frame(width=self.screen_w, height=self.screen_h, background="#ABEBC6")
self.login_section = tk.Frame(width=100, height=100, background="#52BE80")
```

... to this (note the `self` parameter when calling `Frame`):

```
self.login_page = tk.Frame(self, width=self.screen_w, height=self.screen_h, background="#ABEBC6")
self.login_section = tk.Frame(self, width=100, height=100, background="#52BE80")
```

... and likewise for the Search page

That brings up many other problems, but that's the root problem. Every widget you create in each of your "pages" needs to be within the frame of that "page".

Another problem is that you're creating a frame called `root` inside of the main window, and you're putting everything else inside of `root`. However, you never call `pack`, `place`, or `grid` on `root`. Because of that, none of your widgets will show up.

The simplest solution to that problem is to call `pack` on it:

```
root.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
```

You also are showing the "Search" page on startup rather than the login page, so the login button will never show up.

You need to call `self.show_frame("Login")` instead of `self.show_frame("Search")` in your `__init__`.